# Barajar fichas del juego Mahjon

Tags: unity3d, unity, unity2d

Tengo un problema con Unity 3D. Estoy haciendo un juego de Solitario Mahjon, las reglas son simples:

El objetivo es despejar el tablero, eliminando todas las parejas. Las fichas tienen que estar desbloqueadas, es decir, que no tengan ninguna ficha encima o dos fichas a los lados (dch, izq).

He dividido el tablero en vectores Vector3(ancho,pisos,alto). Las fichas las creo en parejas y las barajo.

Adjunto imagen del tablero de Mahjon estandar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que me quedo sin parejas desbloqueadas y no se que hacer.

¿Habría alguna manera de calcular la forma en que el juego coloca las parejas para que no me quede sin fichas desbloqueadas y pueda seguir?

Las fichas las barajo con un método que se llama Barajar:

```
//Baraja las fichas
    void Barajar() {
        //Crear un nº aleatorio para obtener una ficha aleatoria e intencambiarla con otra
        //int aleatorio;
        if (cBarajar == true) {

            for (int i = 0; i < listaDeFichas.Count; i++) {

                if (listaDeFichas[i] != null) {

                    //Crear un nº aleatorio para obtener una ficha aleatoria e intencambiarla con otra
                    //aleatorio = UnityEngine.Random.Range (i, listaDeFichas.Count);
                    int aleatorio = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i, listaDeFichas.Count);


                    //Obtener la posicion de la primera y segunda ficha
                    primeraFicha = listaDeFichas[i].transform.position;
                    segundaFicha = listaDeFichas[aleatorio].transform.position;


                    //Intercambiar posiciones de la 1 y 2 ficha
                    listaDeFichas[i].transform.position = segundaFicha;
                    listaDeFichas[aleatorio].transform.position = primeraFicha;


                }//for(int i = 0;i< listaDeFichas.Count;i++)

            }

            //Cuando estan todas las fichas colocadas llamamos al metodo de asignar coordenadas
            cAsignarCoordenadasDespuesdeBarajar = true; AsignarCoordenadasDespuesdeBarajar();

        }

        cBarajar = false;
    }//Barajar()
```

Estas parejas se colocan aleatoriamente a lo largo del tablero. Cuando encuentro una pareja de fichas desbloqueadas, las selecciono y desaparecen las dos fichas, pero llega un momento en el que me quedo sin fichas parejas/fichas desbloqueadas.

Comment: Un comentario que no responde del todo la pregunta pero busca aportar: Cuando he jugado Mahjong, más de una vez he quedado en que elegí el camino que no era y me quedo sin parejas desbloqueadas. No es eso "parte de la naturaleza del juego"?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo generas el tablero de forma totalmente aleatoria. Esto hace que quizá hayas creado un tablero imposible de resolver. Deberías cambiar la forma de generar el tablero de tal manera que asegures que tiene solución.

No conozco bien las reglas del Mahjon para explicarlo yo mismo, pero buscando un poco he encontrado esto en el que explica las reglas para generar un tablero con solución.

[Algoritmo de Mahjon](https://github.com/MEASHY/Mahjong-Solitaire/wiki/Mahjong-Algorithm)

Está en el apartado Generation ya que está en ingles.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias me he creado 2 listas 1 FichasBarajadas y otra FichasSinBarajar. Lo que hago es ir colocando las fichas en vectores que esten libres y las paso a la lista de FichasBarajadas.

Cada vez coloco una ficha tengo que añadir el vector de la derecha o el de la izquierda si no esta fuera de los limites del tablero(y sino esta ya añadido a la listadeVectoresLibres) y asi las voy colocando.

He creado un metodo que me calcula los vectores/posiciones en el tablero que estan libres y cada vez que coloco 2 fichas(de la misma parejas/tipo) me recalcula las posiciones que estan libres/vectores3.

Muchas gracia por la ayuda me has ayudado mucho...

Pongo el codigo:

//Metodo para saber 1 Vector3(posiciones de fichas) que estan desbloqueados
//se copia toda la lista de fichas SOLO 1 vez a la listaPosicionParaBarajar y se van restando posiciones de esa lista a medida que se van colocando las fichas

void Obtener2PosicionDesbloqueadas(){

```
    int posicionAleatoria;




                for(int a = 0;a < listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count; a ++){

                        posicionAleatoria = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count);

                        Vector3 Resta1 = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] - new Vector3 (1, 0, 0));
                        Vector3 Suma1 = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] + new Vector3 (1, 0, 0));
                        Vector3 Suma1aY = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] + new Vector3 (0, 0.5f , 0));

                                            //Si la lista contiene una posicion encima de...salta ficha
                                            if (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains (Suma1aY)) {
                                            //print ("else if(listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains(Suma1aY)){");
                                            continue;

                                                    //Si la lista contiene una posicion a la inzquierda y a la derecha...salta la ficha
                                                    } else if (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains (Resta1) && listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains(Suma1)) {

                                                        //print ("if (listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains (Resta1) && listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains (Suma1)) {");
                                                        continue;


                                                                }else {

                                                            posicionDesbloqueadaFicha1 = listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar[posicionAleatoria];
                                                            //  listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Remove (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar[posicionAleatoria]);
                                                            break;
                                                            }





}//for(int a = 0;a < listaPosicionDeFichas.Count; a ++){

/*******************************************************************/

for(int a = 0;a < listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count; a ++){

    posicionAleatoria = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count);


    Vector3 Resta1 = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] - new Vector3 (1, 0, 0));
    Vector3 Suma1 = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] + new Vector3 (1, 0, 0));
    Vector3 Suma1aY = (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [posicionAleatoria] + new Vector3 (0, 0.5f , 0));

    //Si la lista contiene una posicion encima de...salta ficha
    if (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains (Suma1aY)) {
        //print ("else if(listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains(Suma1aY)){");
        continue;

        //Si la lista contiene una posicion a la inzquierda y a la derecha...salta la ficha
    } else if (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains (Resta1) && listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Contains(Suma1)) {

        //print ("if (listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains (Resta1) && listaPosicionDeFichas.Contains (Suma1)) {");
        continue;

        //Si la variable posicionFicha1 es = a la ficha escogida...saltar ficha
    }else if(posicionDesbloqueadaFicha1 == listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar[posicionAleatoria]){

        continue;
    }

    //
    else {

        posicionDesbloqueadaFicha2 = listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar[posicionAleatoria];

        break;
    }





}//for(int a = 0;a < listaPosicionDeFichas.Count; a ++){


//Añadimos 2 posiciones a la lista listaPosicionesLibres que nos sirve para colocar las fichas
listaPosicionesLibres.Add (posicionDesbloqueadaFicha1); 
listaPosicionesLibres.Add (posicionDesbloqueadaFicha2); 


//Borramos las posiciones de la lista listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar
listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Remove(posicionDesbloqueadaFicha1);
listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Remove(posicionDesbloqueadaFicha2);

//Borramos los valores repetidos
listaPosicionesLibres = listaPosicionesLibres.Distinct().ToList();
```

}

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************************/

```
//Baraja las fichas colocandolas para que las parejas cuadren
void Barajar() {

    //se copia toda la listadeposiciondefichas SOLO 1 vez a la listaPosicionParaBarajar, se tiene que hacer a traves de º for porque sino se descojona.
    if (copiadaLista1Vez) {
        copiadaLista1Vez = false;

        for (int d = 0; d < listaPosicionDeFichas.Count; d++) {

            listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Add (listaPosicionDeFichas [d]);
        }
    }

//Bucle que nos sirve para añadir Vectores3 a la lista de  listaPosicionesLibres a medida que se va haciendo el calculo para colocarlos por orden en las posisciones libres.
while (listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count > 0) {

    Obtener2PosicionDesbloqueadas ();

    }
//For para colocar las fichas por orden en las posiciones de la listaPosicionesLibres haciendolo asi nos aseguramos que las fichas tengan el mismo Mesh pero sean fichas diferentes
    for (int j = 0; j < listaDeFichas.Count; j++) {

        listaDeFichas [j].transform.position = listaPosicionesLibres [j];
}

//Se recalcula todos los valores de cada ficha
ModificarTodasFichaPrefab ();

}
```